# Shortest Paths with yellow and black edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

Given directed and weighted graph G=(V,E).
There is no negative weighted edge . 
Each edge is colored (black or yellow).

I need to find an algorithm the find the shortest path for a given s ∈ V while every path must be by this rule: color(v<sub>i</sub>,v<sub>i+1</sub>)=color(v<sub>i+3</sub>,v<sub>i+4</sub>), ∀i :1 ≤ i ≤ k-4 while the path is v<sub>1</sub> → ... → v<sub>k</sub>.
The algorithm need to be in O(|V|+|E|log(|V|)).

Comment: You seem to know TeX. Now, it's time to learn some stackoverflow. Please, edit your post to make it readable.

Comment: how can i do it more readable?

Answer (score 4):

As a hint: try modifying Dijkstra's algorithm to store two different priority queues: one containing the cost of a path from the start node to the destination node that ends in a yellow edge, and the cost of a path from the start node to the destination node that ends in a black edge.  Then, update the logic to find the next node to choose to factor in the two queues, and change the decrease-key logic to ensure you update the proper queue with the right information.  This can be done with only a constant factor overhead of a normal Dijkstra's algorithm, so it will take time O(|E| + |V| log |V|).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think it is the right solution. I think i need to adjust the graph to be accurate to the correct possible paths. Your answer seems to be wrong. How you know that a path is correct?

Comment: @BarniWize- You can adjust the correctness proof for Dijkstra's algorithm to work for this modified algorithm.  Suppose that you've computed the shortest alternating path to a set of nodes S and want to expand that set to include a new node v.  My claim is that the algorithm will give you the shortest path.  To see this, suppose it doesn't.  Then there was a path to the node v that started in S, left S by a suboptimal edge, then continued onward.  But in that case, the cost of the path from v out of S across the edge costs more than the path produced by my algorithm, so it's not shorter...

Comment: @BarniWize- ... And therefore my algorithm must produce the shortest alternating paths.

Comment: @BarniWize- There is an another way to do this that works by adjusting the graph, though I think that it's less efficient.  Also, can you please let me know why you think the algorithm is incorrect?  It's possible that I'm mistaken, but from your comments I can see what you think is incorrect.

Comment: how you proove that every shortest path is legal?

Comment: can you write your algorithm in a list of operations? maybee i don't see it clearly.

Comment: @BarniWize- I am assuming that this is a homework question (given how you worded it), so I will leave the details as an exercise.  However, showing you always get legal paths should be simple as long as your decrease-key step always ignores edges of the wrong color.

Comment: i prefer to make a new graph with the correct paths and than run dijakstra on it with weights given by the first graph. for every path i am making it's all legal colors and then get find the minimum weight.

Answer (score 2):

You can either modify Dijkstra's algorithm like templatetypedef suggests, or modify the graph to fit the constraint.

You can recognize the colour constraint with a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), and combine it with your weighted graph to get a graph on which you can apply unmodified Dijkstra, achieving typical Dijkstra runtime.

The exact overhead for the constraint depends on the size of the DFA, but it is constant since the DFA does not depend on the input.

Comment: Isn't that the same algorithm, just expressed differently? In either case you just Dijkstra through the [node]x[edge color] space.